# Migration SVN repo into different structured git repository

Tags: git, svn, migration

my project is currently switching from svn to git repository.

**AS_IS** (SVN):

```
parent-module
    |_module_X
    |     |_trunk
    |     |_branches
    |_module_Y
    |     |_trunk
    |     |_branches
    |_module_Z
    |     |_trunk
    |     |_branches
    |_module_K
         |_trunk
         |_branches
```

I'd like to migrate svn to git repositories obtaining the following structure, still maintaining history:

**TO_BE**(GIT):

```
 parent-module_A
    |_master
        |_module_X
        |_module_Y   
    |_branches
        |_module_X
        |_module_Y

 parent-module_B
    |_master
        |_module_z
        |_module_K   
    |_branches
        |_module_Z
        |_module_K
```

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution here : 
http://bpeirce.me/moving-one-git-repository-into-another.html

I migrating every project module_X , module_Y (only the trunk) with git svn as explained here : http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git

then

I create a bare project git on my server

```
git init --bare parent-module_A
```

So the situation is :

- parent-module_A.git
- module_X.git
- module_Y.git

then I cloned project on my machine

```
git clone http://host/parent-module_A mainproj

git clone module_X.git subproj_tmp
cd subproj_tmp/
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --tree-filter 'mkdir -p .sub; mv * .sub; mv .sub module_X ' -- --all

git gc --aggressive

cd ../mainproj
git remote add module_X ../subproj_tmp
git fetch module_X
git merge module_X/master

git remote rm subproj
git gc --aggressive
git push origin master
```

I repeated the procedure for Module_Y .